# golang read numerous websockets

Tags: sockets, go, websocket

Over the last few weeks I have been lurking around Stack Overflow looking for information related to reading numerous websockets.   Basically, I have numerous hosts that all emit messages over a websocket and I need to aggregate them.

I've accomplished this with Golang thus far for a single websocket connection.  I've accomplished what I am looking for using Python as well, but I would really like to do this in Go!

I have used gorilla's websocket example as well a few others and can successfully read a socket in Go.  However, it seems the websocket server does not completely conform to the typical development practice(s) as using a method such as .forEach or .Each in JS; causes handshake failures.

**Original Version**

```
    package main

    import (
            "fmt"
            "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
            "log"
    )

    var url = "ws://10.0.1.19:5000/data/websocket"

    func main() {
            ws, err := websocket.Dial(url, "", origin)
            if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
            }

            var msg = make([]byte, 512)
            _, err = ws.Read(msg)
            if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Receive: %s\n", msg)
    }
```

I dont actually need to send any data to the socket, I simply need to connect and continue to read it and then I'll aggregate that data into a single stream for performing later operations.

---

### Update (2016-03-19)

After continuous changes and testing with both the gorilla and the old x/net/websocket library, I found that unfortunately it seems the websocket server(s) I am connecting to do not properly adhere to the standard that gorilla wants to use for the handshake.  Either that or I am not telling gorilla how to properly connect.  x/net/websocket connects just fine; I just specify localhost/ as the origin and it seems to work.  I am unsure how to tell gorilla how to do the same to see if it works the same way.  Digging through the DefaultDialer.Dial() has some configuration options but in my modest Go knowledge now I have not found a way to leverage it to do what I am trying to do.

**Current Version (2016-03-19)**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
    // "log"
    "time"
)

var origin = "http://localhost"

type url struct {
    host string
}

func processUrl(host string, messages chan []byte) {
    client, err := websocket.Dial(host, "", origin)
    if err != nil {
        // log.Printf("dial:", err)
    }
    // Clean up on exit from this goroutine
    defer client.Close()
    // Loop reading messages. Send each message to the channel.
    for {
        var msg = make([]byte, 512)
        _, err = client.Read(msg)
        if err != nil {
            // log.Fatal("read:", err)
            return
        }
        messages <- msg
    }
}

func main() {

    // Create an arry of hosts to read websockets from
    urls := []string{
        "ws://10.0.1.90:3000/data/websocket",
        "ws://10.0.2.90:3000/data/websocket",
        "ws://10.0.3.90:3000/data/websocket",
    }

    // Create channel to receive messages from all connections
    messages := make(chan []byte)

    // Run a goroutine for each URL that you want to dial.
    for _, host := range urls {
        go processUrl(host, messages)
    }

    // Print all messages received from the goroutines.
    for msg := range messages {
        fmt.Printf("%d %s\n", time.Now().Unix(), msg)
    }

}
```

RESPONSE (message from ws):

```
    {
        "src_city":"Wayne",
        "dest_city":"Amsterdam",
        "src_country":"US",
        "dest_country":"NL",
        "type":"view"
    }
```

**IOWait Issue(s)**

One issue I am running in to is IOWait errors.  I ran the binary overnight against 10 websockets without any issue.  I ran it against al 488 that I need to run it against and it hit IOWait 2 minutes, etc.  Some of the routine errors I see:

```
    goroutine 72 [IO wait]:
    net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f356149b208, 0x72, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/netpoll.goc:146 +0x66
    net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc20804e610, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x46
    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc20804e610, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x42
    net.(*netFD).Read(0xc20804e5b0, 0xc2080d1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x7f3561498418, 0xb)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x34c
    net.(*conn).Read(0xc20803a150, 0xc2080d1000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/net.go:122 +0xe7
    bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc208005140)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1b3
    bufio.(*Reader).ReadByte(0xc208005140, 0xc2080f22d0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go:199 +0x7e
    golang.org/x/net/websocket.hybiFrameReaderFactory.NewFrameReader(0xc208005140, 0x7f356149b908, 0xc2080f22d0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/shat/go/src/golang.org/x/net/websocket/hybi.go:126 +0xd7
    golang.org/x/net/websocket.(*Conn).Read(0xc2080d7050, 0xc2080f4c00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/shat/go/src/golang.org/x/net/websocket/websocket.go:178 +0xfb
    main.processUrl(0x705010, 0x26, 0xc208004180)
        /home/shat/go/src/github.com/sh4t/scansock/main.go:26 +0x107
    created by main.main
        /home/shat/go/src/github.com/sh4t/scansock/main.go:101 +0x126

    goroutine 73 [IO wait, 2 minutes]:
    net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f356149b158, 0x72, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/netpoll.goc:146 +0x66
    net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc20804e760, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x46
    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc20804e760, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x42
    net.(*netFD).Read(0xc20804e700, 0xc208015000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x7f3561498418, 0xb)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x34c
    net.(*conn).Read(0xc20803a018, 0xc208015000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/net.go:122 +0xe7
    bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc2080042a0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1b3
    bufio.(*Reader).ReadByte(0xc2080042a0, 0x67d6e0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go:199 +0x7e
    golang.org/x/net/websocket.hybiFrameReaderFactory.NewFrameReader(0xc2080042a0, 0x7f356149b908, 0xc2080196d0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/shat/go/src/golang.org/x/net/websocket/hybi.go:126 +0xd7
    golang.org/x/net/websocket.(*Conn).Read(0xc208024240, 0xc208080000, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/shat/go/src/golang.org/x/net/websocket/websocket.go:178 +0xfb
    main.processUrl(0x705190, 0x25, 0xc208004180)
        /home/shat/go/src/github.com/sh4t/scansock/main.go:26 +0x107
    created by main.main
        /home/shat/go/src/github.com/sh4t/scansock/main.go:101 +0x126

    goroutine 74 [IO wait]:
    net.runtime_pollWait(0x7f356149b0a8, 0x72, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/netpoll.goc:146 +0x66
    net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0xc20804e8b0, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:84 +0x46
    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead(0xc20804e8b0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:89 +0x42
    net.(*netFD).Read(0xc20804e850, 0xc2080d9000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x7f3561498418, 0xb)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/fd_unix.go:242 +0x34c
    net.(*conn).Read(0xc20803a160, 0xc2080d9000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/net/net.go:122 +0xe7
    bufio.(*Reader).fill(0xc208005200)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x1b3
    bufio.(*Reader).ReadByte(0xc208005200, 0xc2080f2320, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go:199 +0x7e
    golang.org/x/net/websocket.hybiFrameReaderFactory.NewFrameReader(0xc208005200, 0x7f356149b908, 0xc2080f2320, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/shat/go/src/golang.org/x/net/websocket/hybi.go:126 +0xd7
    golang.org/x/net/websocket.(*Conn).Read(0xc2080d70e0, 0xc2080f4e00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/shat/go/src/golang.org/x/net/websocket/websocket.go:178 +0xfb
    main.processUrl(0x7052d0, 0x27, 0xc208004180)
        /home/shat/go/src/github.com/sh4t/scansock/main.go:26 +0x107
    created by main.main
        /home/shat/go/src/github.com/sh4t/scansock/main.go:101 +0x126
```

I have another binary that attempts to make an initial connection to each web socket address so that I can make sure it is reachable, however that is another issue all together.  My outstanding questions are:

1. How to use Gorilla's websocket implementation to read from the websocket being served by SockJS as I am doing with x/net/websocket's implementation.
2. What could or is the likely cause for the IOWait issue(s) I am seeing?
3. Because I am using []byte as the response, my log file (im just piping stdout to a file) contains lines that have binary data appended to the end.  How should/could I go about converting from the byte slice to just writing it as text/string to stdout as to avoid that?
4. Using the chan, how best is it to pass an additional argument from my process function to return both the host of the websocket the message was returned from to the channel so I can log both the host and the message?  Should I be using a struct to define the channel and have the channel contain what I desire: timestamp, host, message?

For the issue of the IOWait errors, I cannot only imagine (a) a connection cannot be established and the routine is holding it open and eventually throwing an error; (b) it is possible I have too many routines running?  I have tried with 10, 20, 50, and all 400+ where even a version specifying 10 works (as long as all 10 are responding) and a version where 10 does not work as there is a host not responding.

I will likely have subsequent questions, but I appreciate the insight and help.  The channel suggestion definitely got me going.  I've used them once before but don't always understand how best to implement them.  My other project leverages channels and wait groups (wg), but I honestly don't understand the point of one over the other..

Thanks again, your thoughts and suggestions have been wonderful!

*apologies for the weird syntax in this post, I cannot seem to get the editor to remove some of the empty lines around my code elements*

Comment: Worth a mention that server side of the socket is using sockjs ("github.com/fzzy/sockjs-go/sockjs") in Golang.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start a goroutine to read each connection. Send received messages to a channel. Receive from that channel to get messages from all connections.

```
// Create channel to receive messages from all connections
messages := make(chan []byte)

// Run a goroutine for each URL that you want to dial.
for _, u := range urls {
    go func(u string) {
        // Dial with Gorilla package. The x/net/websocket package has issues.
        c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u, http.Header{"Origin":{origin}})
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("dial:", err)
        }
        // Clean up on exit from this goroutine
        defer c.Close()
        // Loop reading messages. Send each message to the channel.
        for {
            _, m, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("read:", err)
                return
            }
            messages <- m
        }
    }(u)
}

// Print all messages received from the goroutines.
for m := range messages {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", m)
}
```

Comment: Nice goroutine.  I checked the Gorilla ReadMessage() implementation and it uses ioutil.ReadAll() which gets a new array allocated for each read.  So it is safe to pass the byte slice to another goroutine and loop around calling c.ReadMessage().  Maybe that was clear to most people.  Wasn't obvious to me so I checked and thought it worth a mention here.

Comment: receiving error: cannot use u (type int) as type string in argument to func literal

I tried to change what I could figure out, I've just started diving into channels in the last few weeks and appreciate the direction, but u is defined as string in the go routine but then in the return is an int.. I see where messages gets the value of m (the response from the server / ws); but why return (u) at the end?

Comment: my own answer to my last question.. not enough args otherwise :)

Comment: I did not mean to edit your post at all, meant to edit my initial one; please refuse the peer edit, just noticed that.

Comment: @MuffinTop you really got me started now!  I am having greater success, but added the current version I am using as well as some questions.  Curious on your opinions or thoughts as to how to better improve the current version.  I would like to use Gorilla's implementation but it never completes a handshake with SockJS on the server side..

Comment: @WeakPointer Could you please elaborate on your comment a little more? Why do we need another goroutine for `c.ReadMessage()` and why pass a byte slice to that goroutine? I think the code of the answer works fine and it does not require another byte slice nor any more goroutines(unless we want to do some other stuff concurrently, such as writing to the websocket or waiting for data from channel, etc).

Comment: @starriet WeakPointer is noting that it is safe to send `m` to the the other goroutine in the answer because `c.ReadMessge()` returns a new slice on each call.

Comment: @BaytaDarell Sorry, I looked through the Gorilla source code, but still I don't understand. Could you please explain it to me? Why is the code in the answer not safe? 1) Is it related to slice? If that's the case, if `m` is not a slice, then it is safe? `c.ReadMessage()` returns a new slice, with a new underlying array, so I don't understand why the slice is unsafe. 2) Is the code unsafe because it can be blocked in `messages <- m`? Thanks!

Comment: The code in the answer is safe.  There are APIs where the backing array of a returned slice is retained and overwritten on the next call to API. See the bufio package for examples. It's not safe to send the slice returned by one of these APIs to another goroutine.  WeakPointer dug into the code and found that ReadMessage is not like those APIs.  ReadMessage returns a new slice w/ backing array on every call. It is safe to send that slice to another goroutine.

Comment: @BaytaDarell What a clear explanation! Thank you so much :)